# Javascript: change styles of elements upon clicking

Tags: javascript

Here is some Javascript I've written:

```
function toggle(clicked_id) {

// Change last button back to light gray.
if (typeof last_id !== 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById(last_id).style.opacity = '.35';
}

// Change current button to dark gray.
document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.opacity = '1';

last_id = clicked_id;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="circle" onClick="toggle(this.id)" id="button1"></div>
<div class="circle" onClick="toggle(this.id)" id="button2"></div>
<div class="circle" onClick="toggle(this.id)" id="button3"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.circle {
    background: black;
    width: .625em;
    height: .625em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom: .35em;
    opacity: .35;
}

.circle:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

There are 3 buttons, with an opacity of '.35' each. Upon hovering on a button its opacity changes to'1'. As you can see, this part is done with CSS. So far so good. What I want now is to permanently change a button's opacity to '1' when it is clicked. It should stay like that until I click another button, at which point it will go back to '.35' and the new button will be at '1'.

I've tried to achieve this with Javascript but I can't figure out why my code doesn't work. Please take a look at my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4yMB/).

P.S. I have assigned a specific id to each button, but I would rather not define these in the stylesheet.

Comment: there is nothing in your JSFiddle

Comment: The link to jsfiddle is to jsfiddle.net and not to your code.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed it.

Comment: Fixed using sdespont's and developer82's suggestions: had to select "No wrap in the left menu in order to declare event with JS inline style and changed CSS class of each button upon being clicked on (final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Hjk9/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new CSS class with opacity 1 and onClick change the class of the object that was clicked, and remove the .circle class from that object.

Answer (score 0):

In fact **your code works**, but the configuration of JSFiddle was wrong : you need to select "No wrap - in " in the left menu if you want to declare event with JS inline style like you do for your `toggle` function : http://jsfiddle.net/d4yMB/2/

```
function toggle(clicked_id) {

    // Change last button back to light gray.
    if (typeof last_id !== 'undefined') {
        document.getElementById(last_id).style.opacity = '.35';
    }

    // Change current button to dark gray.
    document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.opacity = '1';

    last_id = clicked_id;
}
```

Comment: There is still a problem. After a button has been clicked on once, it never highlights on hover anymore. Try clicking the first button, then the second button, for example. Now when you hover on the first button it doesn't get highlighted anymore.